# calling an activity from command line with category and data uri

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

we know that we can call an activity using the follwing command line string,

```
adb shell am
usage: am [start|instrument]
       am start [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
                [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
                [-e <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_VALUE> [-e <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_VALUE> ...]
                [-n <COMPONENT>] [-D] [<URI>]
```

What I want to know is how I set the fields for data uri and category,
for example if the activity class with intent filters like this,

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_edit">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="com.android.notepad.action.EDIT_NOTE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
</intent-filter>
```

How can I call the activity with data uri and category name and mimetype as parameters? Just give me a sample command line string, lets assume the activity be `com.test.test1/.Main`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of command have you already tried out?

Would this work out:

> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -t vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note -n com.test.test1/.Main -d "file:///storage/removable/sdcard1/testFile.txt"